# Examples of ideals of non Noetherian Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, ideals, noetherian, semisimple-lie-algebras

Could someone give an example of ideals of non Noetherian Lie algebra, please?

A Lie algebra $L$ satisfy the maximum condition for ideals, if for each , ascending chain $H_{1} \subseteq H_{2} \subseteq \ldots $ an index $m$ exists such that $H_{i}=H_{k}$ if $m<i$, $m<k .$

We say in short: $ L\in{\rm Max}-\triangleleft$ or $L$ is Noetherian Lie algebra.

Comment: Take any infinite-dimensional abelian Lie algebra. Any subspace is then an ideal.

Comment: I want nontrivial example

Comment: Then you should specify precisely what you consider a "trivial" example. Would you consider an infinite direct sum/product of Lie algebras to be trivial or not?

Comment: I think that abelian Lie algebra is trivial.

Comment: Then take your favorite nontrivial lie algebra and consider its infinite direct sum with itself.

Comment: 1.Could you give me an example and illustrate why this is true? 2. Dose the semi-simple Lie algebra is Noetherian ?